# how can I keep the value of previous cell if the next is 0 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python

Hey I'm trying to keep the value of the column A if the next cell is 0 into column B

so I have this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 10 |

And I want this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 10 | 10 |

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) after replacing `0` with `NaN`

```
df['B'] = df.B.replace(0, np.nan).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

Output

```
    A     B
0   5   5.0
1   0   5.0
2   0   5.0
3  10  10.0
```

Don't forget to import numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Has a side-effect of changing the `dtype` of the column from `int` ot `float`, can solve that by passing `downcast='infer'` to `ffill`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RaghavaDhanya